# Error in node_modules in lightning chart "TypeScript error: Property 'setPattern' is not assignable to the same property in base type"

Tags: lightningchart

I updated the version of Lightning Charts from 3.4.0 to 4.1.0, and now I'm experiencing these errors. How can I resolve them?

[image]

Comment: This seems like a type error on our end, if possible could you attach your tsconfig.json and typescript version? As a possible immediate fix, you can try setting strictFunctionTypes to false in tsconfig. Please let me know if that alleviates the problem.